# Get the result based on column attribute value in csv

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the results of a line based on a value of a column (ID number for example) in a csv file.

let's say i have a csv file with these values:

```
"1.0.0.0,""1.0.0.255"",""16777216"",""16777471"",AU,""Australia"""
"1.0.1.0,""1.0.3.255"",""16777472"",""16778239"",""CN"",""China"""
"1.0.4.0,""1.0.7.255"",""16778240"",""16779263"",AU,""Australia"""
"1.0.8.0,""1.0.15.255"",""16779264"",""16781311"",""CN"",""China"""
"1.0.16.0,""1.0.31.255"",""16781312"",""16785407"",""JP"",""Japan"""
```

I want to select just lines where array country[4] is "AU" , the result shoud be something like:

Country code= AU , name=""Australia""
...
Country code= AU , name=""Australia""

Here's my code:

```
public void run() {

    String csvFile = "D:/country.csv" ;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";

    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                // use comma as separator
            String[] country = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

            System.out.println("...");

            if(country[4]=="AU") { System.out.println("Country code= " + country[4] 
                                 + " , name=" + country[5]);
                                 }

        }
```

ANY IDEAS? Thank you !!

Comment: You should definitely not use split, but a CSV parser to read your CSV content.

Comment: can you give me an example please, Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try the following.

```
if ( country[4].equals( "AU" ) )
{
    System.out.println( "Country code= " + country[4] + " , name=" + country[5] );
}
```

Using '==' checks the references to the Objects are equal. Whereas, '.equals' function will compare the actual content of the String.